# Passing DateTime Object In API in C#

Tags: c#, api, datetime

I am working on Lobs.com Letters API. I am trying to retrieve the list of All letters from the API by the Date_Created parameter via GET Method. But I am not finding any way to get it done successfully. There is always an error showing "date_created must be an object". Please see the below screen shots from Visual studio as Well as from PostMan.
[Exception From Visual Studio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aw12u.png) and from postman is
[Error From postman](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pxtYx.png).
Moreover the API requires me to pass the dateTime in ISO 8601 format and I have concerned different posts on this forum and tried the accepted solution.

Please guide how Can i pass this DateTime object in the url or correct me if my format is wrong. I have also serialized the DateTime object.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1(v=vs.110).aspx):

> The "O" or "o" standard format specifier represents a custom date and time format string using a pattern that preserves time zone information and emits a result string that complies with ISO 8601.

So... use "o" instead of "s".

```
d2.ToString("o");
```

Also, not sure you need to bother with the JavaScriptSerializer.  If anything, you'd want to URL-encoded the value, but I don't think an ISO 8601 date needs escaping.

Comment: So how should I pass the converted DateTime in the URL as an object ?